# Simplest option for backup or restore point for minimal Centos install

Tags: linux, backup, centos, system-restore

Experiencing some strange voodoo with a recent Centos 7 + MATE install. I'm pretty sure the issues(Houdini doesn't launch anymore, strange behavior in installing plugins etc) are driver related and want to 'roll back' to an earlier version.
However I didn't create any backup or restore point.
Can any linux gurus suggest the best method for creating backups or restore points of just the system + any drivers installed?

My plan now is to start from scratch and reformat my SSD, do a complete reinstall. There goes another weekend!
Also was wondering, are other flavors of linux equally sensitive to driver related issues?

Perhaps switch to Ubuntu, Fedora, or even downgrade to Centos 6 from 7?
Any feedback appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way without installing any additional tooling would be to make a block based backup of your disk using [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/). It will make a bit-by-bit backup of your system, which you can use to recover.

In my experience, driver issues on Linux are one of my least favourite problems to deal with. Usually they're hard to debug and fix. You might try and see if another distro has native support for your device, which would be preferable if you don't have any other reason to stick to a particular distro. If no distro has native support for your device, you're probably going to run into problems with all of them (they're all based on the Linux kernel).

Answer (score 0):

You can try and rollback package installation with `yum history`.

The above command will give you a list of transactions. You can see all that was done in that transaction with `yum history info #` (where # is the transaction number).

Then undo with `yum history undo #`.

Keep in mind that not all the packages can be rolled back.

With that out of the way, your diagnosis of "driver issue" seems biased and hurried.
Try to start houdini from the command line and report relevant error messages.